# Can I add an ActiveX control to a Comctlib.Toolbar (mscomctl) control?

Tags: vb6, activex, toolbar, comctl32

$Hello_all,

I'm adding functionality to a VB6 application (yes, I know, an amazing task :P) and I need to drop an ActiveX control (it looks like a button but does more things) into a comctlib (Microsoft Common Controls) Toolbar.

Is this possible at all? I don't mind using the Winapi, interop or whatever is needed as I really need this feature. If this is not possible with the Comctlib control is there another toolbar control for VB6 where I can drop other ActiveX controls?

Thanks in advance for helping me with this outdated technology.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. The MS Common Controls 6.0 toolbar is a container control, so you can put anything you want on it – you'd just have to manage its position manually as it wouldn't be one of the built-in components.

Comment: @Antagony: this is simply not true. The toolbar is a container of buttons. It only has a buttons collection where you add Button objects.

Comment: It **is** a container regardless of the intrinsic `Buttons` collection. One of the `Style` properties for a button is `PlaceHolder` – which creates a blank area in the desired position – you can then simply place *any* other control you want on top of that blank area. If its position is dynamic due to buttons being optionally shown/hidden, you will have to move any controls you place there programmatically, but that's relatively straightforward.

Comment: Looking at this again it would appear *some* controls are not given a high enough precedence to appear on top of the placeholder's buttons. However, this is easily remedied by placing them inside a borderless picturebox.

Comment: @Antagony: if you set your second comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to its intrinsic `Buttons` collection, the toolbar acts as a general container. So, to position any (non-lightweight*) control/s you want between existing buttons, insert a new button and set its `Style` property to `PlaceHolder` – that creates a blank area in the desired position – and place your control/s there.

Of course you will have to manually reposition any such control/s if you dynamically show/hide/add/remove buttons at runtime.

* *To display lightweight controls, you could place them inside any other container control – e.g. a borderless PictureBox – first.*